# Selenium(Python) Как закрыть браузер по session_id

Tags: python, selenium

Всем привет, у меня скрипт сохраняет сессию браузера в файл json и мне нужно уже из другого браузера его закрыть, как это сделать?

Comment: Советую изучить этот раздел [документации Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/remote_webdriver/). Во всяком случае, если Вы желаете получить возможность на более развернутый ответ, Вам необходимо предоставить фрагмент Вашего решения.

Comment: Я посмотрел однако когда я сделал все так как было в инструкции я получаю ошибку, изменил пост с кодом скрином и ошибкой.